# Checkout each subversion revision into its own directory?

Tags: svn, version-control, git-svn

I want to checkout each revision of an SVN archive to its own directory.

My poorly worded last question prompted answers telling me to create a duplicate SVN repository, however, this is explicitly NOT what I want.

I'm not looking for a duplicated SVN archive - each revision specifically must go in its own folder.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you want to do this - if you're wanting to convert an SVN repo to git, I think there are existing tools to do it..

Comment: I'm not trying to do that. If I wanted to convert to git, I would have said that :P

Comment: Then why didn't you say what you *are* trying to do?

Comment: How are you misinterpreting both the first and last sentences? It's pretty explicitly written there...

Comment: How are you misinterpreting my first comment? I asked why, regarding your first sentence. I was probing for an [X/Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). But hey, you got your answer, so never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure why you would want to do this but it should be pretty easy to write some kind of script to do it. You just need to figure out that the HEAD revision number is and then script the checkouts. For example with php (cause its the easiest to write off the top of my head):

```
$head = 5042;
$base = 1;
$basepath = "/path/to/folder";
$svnbin = '/usr/bin/svn';
$svnurl = 'http://svn.whatever.com/path/to/repo';

$cmdtpl = "$svnbin co -r%d $svnrl %s";

for ($n = $base; $n <= $head; $n++) {
   $dir = $basepath . '/r' . $n; // folders names like r1, r2, etc.
   $cmd = sprintf($cmdtpl, $n, $dir);

   exec($cmd, $out, $ret);

   // blow up if it fails!
   if($ret) {
      throw new Exception("Command ($cmd) failed with return value \"$ret\".");
   }

}
```